# Unable to invoke Java for loop and count backwards

Tags: java, for-loop

I cannot get the below Java for loop to invoke.

I can get it to count forwards from 0 but not backwards from 10.

Code:

```
for (int repetitions = 10; repetitions <= 2; repetitions--) {
 //determines if userInput can be divided by 2 - 10 

System.out.println("for invoked!" + repetitions); //test code

if ((userInput % repetitions) > 0) {

divisibleByTwoToTen = false;

System.out.println("count " + repetitions + " " + divisibleByTwoToTen); //test code

}

else {

divisibleByTwoToTen = true;

System.out.println("count " + repetitions + " " + divisibleByTwoToTen); //test code

}

}
```

Expected:  9 loops and the application of either true or false to the divisibleByTwoToTen boolean variable.

Actual: Doesn't invoke.

Comment: `repetitions <= 2` is immediately false. Did you mean `>= 2`?

Comment: Yes, just realised this after a lunch break...  Thanks @shmosel!

Answer (score 0):

If you stare at the screen long enough, you will completely miss the answer...

The test condition should have been repetitions >= 2 not repetitions <= 2 and hence the condition was never satisfied.

Dooh!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be like this -

```
for (int repetitions = 10; repetitions >= 2; repetitions--) {
 //determines if userInput can be divided by 2 - 10 
 System.out.println("for invoked!" + repetitions); 
}
```